# Different range request response in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am currently testing some JavaScript that makes a GET request (ie. XMLHttpRequest with "get") with a Range header. Because the request is cross-domain, I'm implementing access control headers in the response as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Preflighted_requests

What's confusing me however is that my current server setup is working in Chrome but not in Firefox. Specifically, when I run the JavaScript in Chrome I'm getting back a chunk of the requested data, just like I want. In Firefox however I'm getting error code 501 on request method OPTIONS

At first that seems like the OPTIONS request method needs to be handled by the server, but that works in Chrome so it looks like this is a red herring and something else is wrong. Currently the following response headers are implemented, perhaps this is where the problem lies:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Anyone have any insight in what I need to do? Do Chrome and Firefox handle cross-domain restrictions differently?

Comment: Firefox is sending the OPTIONS request per the documentation you cite.  It sounds like your server is responding with a 501 instead of a 200.  Have you looked into why?

Comment: Does Chrome not send the OPTIONS request? In my testing it seemed like it did, and I cannot tell why the browsers are behaving differently, but I'm not entirely sure. What is that for anyway?

Comment: I have no idea what Chrome is doing here, but if they're both sending OPTIONS then the behavior difference is on the server side...  As for what the OPTIONS is for, it's to make sure the target site is not getting attacked by your site.  See http://dev.w3.org/2006/waf/access-control/#preflight-request